Should Jews make Birkat Ha’ilonot on hydroponic fruit trees
According to Halacha,  should  the beracha of Birkat Ha’ilonot, made  when seeing a fruit tree for the first time during the month of Nissan, be made on fruit trees which are grown hydroponically or no? Is it a different din to regular fruit trees, or the same?

Why would you think it is not so?

According to Machon Hatorah VeHaAretz the חיי אדם considered hydroponic growth as not being "earth based" and said the Bracha on their produce is Shehakol.
Some later Poskim do consider them "earth based" for Brachot, but possibly less so for other issues.
Sources: Here and here - worth reading to get the full Halachic picture.
The Gemara (Brachot 43b) says "אמר רב יהודה: האי מאן דנפיק ביומי ניסן וחזי אילני דקא מלבלבי" - one who sees trees that are in blossom says Birkat Ha’ilonot. There are Poskim (ibid note 42 quoting שו"ת אור לציון חלק ד פרק כד - דיני הסכך) who say that hydroponic growth cannot be used as Schach to cover a Sukka - in which case one probably could not say Birkat Ha’ilonot on them either.
CLOR if we pasken like Rav Ben Zion Abba Shaul zt"l in this case.
